# Notification for additional drivers

Tags: jockey

Today I installed Ubuntu 11.10 in my HP laptop well everything goes well installation and updates.

I then got a notification on the taskbar for additional drivers: *No propritery drivers are in use on this system.*

What I read on the tool that opens after clicking the message is:

> Proprietry driver do not have public source code that ubuntu developer
>   are free to modify security updates and correction depend solely on
>   the respnsiveness of the manufacture ubuntu cannot fix or improve
>   these drivers.
>
> 1. ATI/AMD proprietry FGLRX graphic driver( post release update)
>      2.ATI/AMD proprietry FGLRX graphic driver
>
> ATI/AMD propreitry FGLRX graphics driver(post release update)
>
> tested by ubuntu developers
>
> License propreitry
>
> 3D accelerated propreitry graphic drivers for ATI cards.
>
> This driver is required to fully utilise the 3D potential of some ATI
>   graphic and as well as provide 2D accelerate newer card.

Do I need to active this driver in order to accomplish the complete installation?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu, by default, installs the open-source driver for your video card; the dialog you saw suggests you to install the proprietary closed-source driver provided by Ati. So, it is not necessary for you to do this operation, until you are not experiencing graphic problems with the open-source driver or if you don't have particular needs (the open-source driver often doesn't offer 3D acceleration for most video cards, then if you need it, you can try installing the proprietary driver). The same applies also for Nvidia video cards.